# Is there a way to limit data size at C++ compile time and produce a compile error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have build a tool that enable students to compile and test their own C++ code on line (on a protected environment).

I would like to check, at compile time, that the total amount of data size in a program does not exceed a certain size, and produce a compile error if it does.

(immediate goal : limit c++ std::array size )

I did not find information on the Web.

My compile chain is :

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Waddress -std=c++11 -lm -fstack-protector -lm -o exename srcname
```

Thanks for help.

**EDIT 1**

I give them a skeleton, and they have to complete where (here) is specified :

"Complete the program (here) with the definition of 'produitTableau' that get an a 2 dimensional array of integer et an integer  and that apply  'calcul' function to each of its vallues and that returns the modified array." (in french...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

const int NB = 3;

int calcul (int a, int b);
array<array<int, NB>,NB> produitTableau(array<array<int, NB>,NB> t, int a);

int main()
{
    /* déclaration et initialisation  */
    array<array<int, NB>,NB> tab ;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    for (int i=0;i<NB;i++) {for(int j=0; j<NB; j++) {cin >> tab[i][j];}}

    /* traitement et résultat  */
    tab = produitTableau(tab, x);

    /* résultat */
    for (int i=0; i < NB; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < NB; j++) {
        cout << tab[i][j] << " ";
      }
    }

  return 0;
}

int calcul(int a, int b)
{
   return a*b;
}

**(here)**
```

I expect them to write something like (I check the result with a test data set that is store in a text file and that is used as input data) :

```
array<array<int, NB>,NB> produitTableau(array<array<int, NB>,NB> t, int a)
{
    for (int i=0; i < NB; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < NB; j++) {
        t[i][j] = calcul(t[i][j] , a);
      }
    }

   return t;

}
```

*** the array is passed by value ***

So I would check that the total amount of data used is thess than a certain value, for example : 10.000 bytes.

May be it could be the exe file...I don't know that.

Comment: But what kind of data exactly are you trying to limit? Depending on how mentioned `std::array` is used, it's either going to land in .bss, stack or heap - depending on how your student decides to use it. You'd have to limit all of those (plus likely .data as well).

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific than that, it seems you're a bit mushy on some details; What exactly are you trying to achieve with your limiting? This may be an X/Y situation (i.e. you might be trying to solve the wrong problem here)

Comment: Can you just limit the memory of the *protected environment*?

Comment: "protected environment" is not the right term : it is protected in the sens that students need an id and a password...

Comment: I have found a compile option that give a warning if the siez of an objet is greater that x : "...warning: size of 't2' is 4000000 bytes [-Wlarger-than=]| ". That could be the solution. But to turn a warning to an error ? but it is not the total of array used...

Comment: I have found a compile option -Werror that turns warning to errors...

Comment: Not related to your problem. But if you teach someone c++ why do you then use `int` for `NB` instead of the correct type `std::size_t` (`unsigned int`)? Because the `N` of an `std:array` is `std::size_t` as it does not make sense to have an array with a negative size.

Comment: your are right, but it is for beginner students (mathematics and computer science) to apply algorithmic (procedural) to a programming language. And C++ because we use C++ in following years. But may be we should...and it should be the same for indices (i, j...). We generally do that to make things more simple, but in that case, mathematics would use natural numbers. I will discuss it ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will implement to parts :

1. check contraints fixed by source source
2. check size limits using compiler options

## # 1. check contraints fixed by source source #

from @einpoklum advice,

### ## 1.1 make of copy of 'array' header file to 'myArray' and add 'assert' ##

```
...
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
    struct array
    {
       typedef _Tp                        value_type;
      ...
       typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>   const_reverse_iterator;

       // Support for zero-sized arrays mandatory.
       value_type _M_instance[_Nm ? _Nm : 1];

       static_assert(_Nm == NB, "Check array size...");  <<<<<<<<<<<<

  ... continue...
```

### ## 1.2 Define array size in the main program ##

```
const unsigned int NB = 10;  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<w
#include <iostream>
#include "myArray.h" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
...
```

### Example 1 :

```
const unsigned int NB = 10;
...
#include "myArray.h"
...
int main()
{
    array<int, 11> tab;
    ...
}
```

At compile time : **error: static assertion failed: Check array size...**

## # 2. check size limits using compiler options #

use compiler option to enforce control (limit the risks of misuse : C array for example, or multiple definition of array, ...

g++ compiler options :

1. -Wlarger-than=x : check size in bytes of an object
2. -Wframe-larger-than=x : check size of a function
   [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options][1]
   -Wframe-larger-than=byte-size
3. -Werror : to turn Warnings to Errors

Example 1 : ( -Wlarger-than=10000 )

```
const int NB = 100;
...
array<array<int, NB>,NB> tab ;
```

produces the error : ...error: size of 'tab' is 40000 bytes [-Werror=larger-than=]|

Example 2 : (simplified example) ( -Wframe-larger-than=10000 )

```
int main()
{
    array<array<int, 100>,100> tab ;
    int x;
    ...
    tab = produitTableau(tab, x);

    return 0;
}

array<array<int, 100>,100> produitTableau(array<array<int, 100>,100> t, int a)
{
...
   return t;
}
```

produces the error : ...error: the frame size of 80016 bytes is larger than 10000 bytes [-Werror=frame-larger-than=]|

80016 bytes = 
 tab  10000*4=40000 bytes
 + parameter passed by value = 40000 bytes
 + other variables...

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you prevent includes of anything else, you could adapt `std::array<T, N>` so as to limit N to some maximum size; then make the students include that array instead.

The adaptation might be as simple as adding:

```
static_assert(N == NB, "For this homework assignment you can only use arrays of NB elements");
```

within the array class, and earlier in the file,

```
constexpr const size_t NB = 123;
```

Remember not to change the original array file of course! Make a copy (perhaps even change the name to clarify it's a custom array).

Comment: that could be a solution : it requires a class per assignment. But what about multidimensional array (matrix for example) ?

Comment: @PatrickDezecache: That would be different. Remember, though, that the standard library does not have matrix/tensor containers.

Comment: as matrix, i mean 2 dimensional array, each dimension has gotis own value, not always square matrix.

Comment: @PatrickDezecache: Yes, I realize that, but it's a different question than the one you asked. Generally, I'd say - choose whatever implementation of a matrix you like, make a copy, and constraint its dimensions - either statically or dynamically.